# How to open CBR comic books on PocketBook?

Tags: file-format

Currently, PocketBook does not support the comic books [CBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_archive) file format. Is there any way to open them **without** prior extracting and converting it on PC?

Comment: CBZ format works on your device?

Answer (score 0):

The firmware update 5.20 released on March 2019 opened a support both for CBR and CBZ formats (the performance was further improved in later ones).

If you have any of these models:
https://pocketbook.ch/en-ch/news/pocketbook-firmware-update-6-5-2-ch
it may be worth to check and update the firmware if possible.